# Mensaje de error en las llaves foraneas con postgress

Tags: postgresql

Estoy tratando de insertar productos en una tabla llamada products, pero me sale este mensaje de error :

> ERROR:  inserción o actualización en la tabla «products» viola la
> llave foránea «products_category_id_fkey» DETALLE:  La llave
> (category_id)=(4) no está presente en la tabla «categories».

Y este es todo el código:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customers;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
CREATE TABLE customers(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(50),
address VARCHAR(80)
);

CREATE TABLE categories (
    id_category SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    category_name VARCHAR(30),
    description VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE invoices(
    customer_id INTEGER,
    invoice_number SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at DATE NOT NULL,
    subtotal INTEGER NOT NULL,
    taxes INTEGER NOT NULL,
    final_amount INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) REFERENCES customers(id)
);

CREATE TABLE products(
    id_product SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    category_id INTEGER,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT,
    price INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(category_id) REFERENCES categories(id_category)
);

CREATE TABLE product_list(
    invoice_id INTEGER,
    price INTEGER,
    quantity INTEGER,
    total INTEGER,
    product_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(invoice_id) REFERENCES invoices(invoice_number),
    FOREIGN KEY(product_id) REFERENCES products(id_product)
);
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Creo que esta claro el error, te falta una entrada con id_category = 4 en la tabla categories para poder insertar ese valor en la tabla products, products la esta referenciando

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta Roger, en realidad soy nuevo en esto del Postgres, como debería quedar referenciada, puesto que la he ingresado de varias maneras y no me inserta los artículo, aún siguiendo tu observación, gracias nuevamente.

Comment: El tema es que debes tener en categories ese categoria con id_category = 4, antes de insertar cualquier producto con de esa categoria, es integridad referencial de los modelos relaciones

Answer (score -1):

La tabla products está relacionada con la tabla categories mediante la llave foránea `category_id`. Por tanto para poder insertar un producto con `category_id = 4` primero debes insertar esa categoría en tu tabla categories, es decir, alguna de las categorías de esa tabla (`categories`) debe tener `id_category = 4`.